# How to add label to percentage bar in css and html?

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I did a percentage bar with css But I want write label with the number in percentage in it or beside it when I write it change

CSS code:

```
#progressbar {
    background-color: #999;
    border-radius: 10px; /* (height of inner div) / 2 + padding */
    padding: 0.5px;
    max-width:150px;
    font-size: 9px;
}
#progressbar > div {
    background-color:red;
    /* Adjust with JavaScript */
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width:150px;
    font-size: 12px;    
}
```

and in body

```
echo" Excellent       <div id="."progressbar".">
  <div style="."width:".(($ex*150)/100)."px;".">".$ex."%</div>
</div>";
```

How can I want write a word beside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if I can improve it :)

```css
#progressbar {
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* (height of inner div) / 2 + padding */
  padding: 0.5px;
  max-width: 150px;
  font-size: 9px;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar > div {
  background-color: red;
  /* Adjust with JavaScript */
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 150px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#progressbar span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressbar">
  <span>Excellent</span>
  <div style="width:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE: (request for text alongside the progress bar)**

```css
#progressbar {
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* (height of inner div) / 2 + padding */
  padding: 0.5px;
  max-width: 150px;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#progressbar > div {
  background-color: red;
  /* Adjust with JavaScript */
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#progressBarContainer span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressBarContainer">
  <div id="progressbar">
    <div style="width:50%;"></div>
  </div>
  <span>Excellent</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . But if i   want  the word excellent beside the line.what i do

Comment: @A.Nabil Would you like it on the left or right side of the progress bar?

Comment: I want the word excellent appear on the right side of the progress bar  when i write it without css it appear after the line progressbar

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $width = (($ex*150)/100);
?>
Excellent <div id="progressbar">
  <div style="width: <?php echo $width ?>">
    <?php echo $ex ?>%
  </div>
</div>
```

[Phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dkjy-8ik5)